# Were Soviet warships allowed to use the Panama canal?

Tags: soviet-union, cold-war

During the Cold War, were Soviet naval vessels allowed to use the Panama canal?

I'm aware that no Soviet warships happened to use the canal during the Cold War.  Was there a rule aganst them transiting the canal, or were they free to do so, even if none actually did?

For example, if any Soviet warships went between Atlantic and Pacific by going via a longer route, this would be evidence that they *would* have used the canal, but that they weren't allowed to.

Comment: -1 was by me, as the first page of Google search "panama canal cold war soviet" is full of answers for this question.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski, when I google those terms, I'm not seeing any actual answers to this question.

Comment: 4 out of 5 first results contain the answer in their Google description and provide nice details after clicking provided links. 3rd one is an article recommended by both choster and RI Swamp Yankee. But as I see more votes of people suggesting that this question shows research effort, I understand that asking Google first is not necessary at this website and will conform to that for the future.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski Please don't conform to that.

Comment: Shhh guys, if you wanted to game our area51 results you would ask any question you could think of.

Comment: Haha I didn't down vote because I was thinking what Nathan said.

Answer (score 16):

The Panama Canal was [closed to Soviet warships](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/7768743.stm) for the duration of the Cold War. On December 6, 2008, the destroyer *Admiral Chabanenko" became the first Russian or Soviet military vessel to transit the Canal [since 1944](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/russia/3628867/First-Russian-warship-uses-Panama-Canal-since-1944.html).

Soviet-flagged civilian vessels seem to have been permitted, at least for a while. A *Canberra Times* article from 22 April 1948 reports that [23 Russian [sic] vessels had traversed the Canal](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/2742932) in 1948.

Comment: Do you have any citation that the canal was closed to Soviet warships?  The article you linked says that the transit had no political significance as the canal is "open to all the world's ships".

Comment: The article also doesn't say anything at all about the *reason* their ships didn't traverse the canal. For all we know, it could be that the USA had no problem with it, but the Soviets didn't want to make their warships vulnerable by putting them essentially under USA control for a canal traversal.

Comment: http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/country_profiles/1229333.stm says "The canal was shut to the Soviet Union during the Cold War." Even if there was no official policy, the Panama Canal Zone (encompassing the entire canal) was an overseas U.S. territory until 1999, and the U.S. could have simply declined requests for Soviet naval ships to enter its territorial waters. As for the quotation, it reflects the political status of the canal in 2008, not during the Cold War.

Comment: I recently read http://www.amazon.com/Path-Between-Seas-Creation-1870-1914/dp/0671244094/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1360805797&sr=1-1&keywords=panama+canal , which IIRC said that USA policy was to let anyone through, to discourage the canal becoming a target for attack. However, the canal also has defenses (manned by Americans) just in case, which would have to make anybody not in good smell with the USA nervous about running their really valuable warships through it. So it could just be that the USSR felt it was off limits to their warships for strategic reasons.

Comment: @choster "could have declined" is quite different from "was shut"...

Comment: @T.E.D. your "*the canal also has defenses (manned by Americans)*" comment implies that the Sovs thought the Americans might sink Soviet ships **in the canal**.

Comment: @RonJohn - I'm not an expert on these things, but I suspect someone could do more damage by destroying the locks. I suppose trying to take over the canal by force might be an option too.

Comment: @T.E.D. correct that destroying the locks is how you'd render the canal useless.  But you do that via stand-off missiles, or covert KGB/Spetsnaz teams, not warships in the Canal.

Comment: @RonJohn - If I were a Soviet, I would have been more concerned about my ship being held hostage. Possibly even boarded and searched if it happened to be carrying anything sensitive (which all warships would have been). It would also have been a great place from which to defect. The Soviets had a fear of that after a [submarine tinder captain did it in 1961](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonas_Ple%C5%A1kys)

Comment: @T.E.D. as far as being held hostage... I wonder if the US (or Panamanians) had the right to board and search vessels for contraband *just because*.  (For example, Soviets transited the Bosphorus and Dardanelles without fear of NATO member Turkey boarding them and "searching for drugs".)  But good point about defecting.

Comment: "Right" doesn't necessarily enter into it. North Korea still has possession of a [US surveillance ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Pueblo_(AGER-2)) they sized in international waters during the Cold war. The USA protested, but fat lot of good that did them after (for all they knew) the North Koreans had already let the Soviets on board to pick over everything the ship had. Excuses can always be found, or worst case apologies made, after enemy intelligence has all the goodies.

Comment: @RonJohn or take a civilian cargo ship (preferably false or third nation flagged), stuff it full of explosives, and let it go BOOM in the locks. Suicide mission, obviously.

Answer (score 7):

No, no Russian warships from 1944 until 2008 traveled through the Panama Canal. Here is a [BBC web article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/7768743.stm) on the topic.